# How can I send a message directly into a dead letter queue in azure service bus (java)?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a servicebusqueuetrigger function that takes a string off the service bus and calls another api, if that api call does not return a 200, I want to move that string as a meesage into a dead letter queue.  How can I do this?

So far I have this...

```
public class myEventsConsumerFunction {

    @FunctionName("myEventTrigger")
    public void myEventTrigger(
            @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name = "message", queueName = "%QUEUE_NAME%", connection = "ServiceBusConnection") String message,
            final ExecutionContext context) throws MSPException {
            int responseCode = callApi(message);
                    if(responseCode!=200){
            String ConnectionString = "connectionstring"
            QueueClient sendClient = new QueueClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString, queueName), ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
            //
            //how do i send my String message to dead letter queue here?
            //


        }
```

I see a bunch of methods in queue client called deadletter, but they take a UUID as a parameter (I am not sure what that is), and not a message String.

Answer (score 1):

The key to the problem is that the Java-based azure sdk package of offcial didn't not write the MessageReceiver class. (As far as I know, the official only implements the IMessageReceiver interface of C#) If it is C#, you can use it directly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver?view=azure-dotnet

But for java, The official has not yet implemented this, only a interface:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.imessagereceiver?view=azure-java-stable

> I see a bunch of methods in queue client called deadletter, but they
> take a UUID as a parameter (I am not sure what that is), and not a
> message String.

I know this, but it is not based on messages, if you create an object of queueclient and use the method, it will tells you no receiver:

[image]

In summary, I think this is an unfinished feature, and maybe it can be updated in a future sdk version. But not now, unless you read the underlying code and implement the IMessageReceiver interface yourself, otherwise it will be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, the [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/407) is still open.